# Spivak calculus 7. ch 22: Convergence of a continued fraction sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

This exercise is has a "small" modification, but I haven't been able to solve it yet and I wanted some advice! thanks!

For any positive integers $a$ and $b$ consider the sequence
$$
a_{1}=a, \quad\text{and}\quad a_{n}=\frac{b}{2 a+a_{n-1}}\quad \text{for} \; n \geq 2
$$
Show that the sequence converges to the value of
$$
\sqrt{a^{2}+b}-a
$$
And use the first item to show that a development in continued fractions of $$ \sqrt{a^{2}+b}$$ is
$$\sqrt{a^{2}+b}=a+\frac{b}{2 a+\frac{b}{2 a+\frac{b}{2 a+\cdots}}} $$

---

**Context from Comments**

I've been trying, but I don't understand what $\left | a(n)-a(m) \right |\leq kd_{e}(n-m)=k\sqrt{n^{2}-m^{2}}$ has to do with $\sqrt{a^2+b}-a$. Then, without loss of generality, and considering that $a$ and $b$ are positive integers, so $a^{2}+b<a^{2}+b^{2}\Rightarrow \sqrt{a^{2}+b}-a<\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}= d_{e}(a,b)$ in order to find a relationship between $\left |a(a)-a(b)  \right |$ and $kd_{e}(a,b)$

Comment: Are you able to show the $a_n = \cdots$ map is contractive on some interval containing $\sqrt{a^2+b}-a$, the largest such interval, and that $\sqrt{a^2+b}-a$ is a fixed point of that map?

Comment: @EricTowers I've been trying, but I don't understand what $\left | a(n)-a(m) \right |\leq kd_{e}(n-m)=k\sqrt{n^{2}-m^{2}}$ has to do with $\sqrt{a^2+b}-a$. Then, without loss of generality, and considering that $a$ and $b$ are positive integers, so $a^{2}+b<a^{2}+b^{2}\Rightarrow \sqrt{a^{2}+b}-a<\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}= d_{e}(a,b)$ in order to find a relationship between $\left |a(a)-a(b)  \right |$ and $kd_{e}(a,b)$

Comment: @Andre785858 Can you please insert this attempt into the question post, because this fulfills the context criterion for questions, and is important for future visitors/ answerers? Thank you for providing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following I am assuming that $x \ge 0$.

Let $f(x) = {b \over 2a+x}$, $g(x) = f(f(x))$. Note that $g'(x) = {b^2 \over (2ax +b+4 a^2)^2}$ and $|g'(x)| \le {b^2 \over (b+4 a^2)^2} < 1$. In particular, $g$ is a contraction and hence has a unique fixed point $x^*$. It follows that $x^*$ is the unique fixed point of $f$ as well.

Hence the sequence $a_n$ converges to some $a^*$ and we must have $a^* = f(a^*)$.
Solving shows that $a^* = \sqrt{a^2+b} -a$.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Why the delete?

Comment: I have moved the context from the comments into the question. However, the context was there (in comments) prior to this answer being posted.

Comment: Unfortunately, Spivak doesn't get to contraction mapping until Exercise 23, several pages later.

Comment: @TedShifrin Bummer, I initially had a long winded proof that showed the increasing part of the sequence converged but was happy to discover the above instead :-(.

Comment: @copper.hat I'd like to see the way you proof it long form

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: In the spirit of the previous part of the exercise, Spivak intends for you to consider separately the subsequences of even terms and odd terms. One is increasing, the other decreasing, and you can check that their limits agree.